# How to access TFS URL 'http://msitvstf1:8080/tfs/RXD' from WCF Service hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to access TFS URL 'http://xxxxxx:8080/tfs/xxx' from WCF service which is hosted in Azure. I am able to access the URL from On-Premise server but not from Cloud. How can I have access to this TFS URL from Azure Cloud Service ? Do I need to use Site-to-site VPN connection in azure? Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to provide a way for external parties to access your TFS server. Either by exposing the server to the internet with a proper fully qualified domain name, or by setting up a VPN connection between Azure and your on-premise network. Even then it may be required (depending on firewall settings and which ports are allowed through) to supply the fully qualified domain name when connecting. e.g. `msitvstf1.mycompany.internal` and to make sure that your Azure VMs are configured to use your internal DNS server, if this domain name is not publicly registered.

A VPN is not required per-se, you can also configure the Azure firewall and your own companies firewall to let the data through without the protection of a VPN tunnel. Adding VPN adds another layer of security, which a lot of IT departments find useful and often require.